# I tried installing Qt4.8.1 on CentOS8 by building from source code but I get the following error:

Tags: qt, centos8

```
../3rdparty/libpng/pngerror.c:324:48: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
             for (; i<(sizeof msg)-1 && parm != '\0' && parm < pend; ++i)
                                                ^~~~
In file included from ../3rdparty/libpng/privatepng.cpp:8:
../3rdparty/libpng/pngrtran.c: In function ‘void PrivatePng::png_set_crc_action(PrivatePng::png_structp, int, int)’:
../3rdparty/libpng/pngrtran.c:52:21: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
          png_warning(png_ptr,
          ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
             "Can't discard critical data on CRC error");
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../3rdparty/libpng/pngrtran.c:54:7: note: here
       case PNG_CRC_ERROR_QUIT:                                /* Error/quit */
       ^~~~
In file included from ../3rdparty/libpng/privatepng.cpp:13:
../3rdparty/libpng/pngwrite.c: In function ‘void PrivatePng::png_set_filter(PrivatePng::png_structp, int, int)’:
../3rdparty/libpng/pngwrite.c:1033:29: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
          case 7: png_warning(png_ptr, "Unknown row filter for method 0");
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../3rdparty/libpng/pngwrite.c:1035:10: note: here
          case PNG_FILTER_VALUE_NONE:
          ^~~~
make[1]: *** [Makefile:75547: .obj/release-shared/privatepng.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ows/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.1/src/gui'
make: *** [Makefile:386: sub-gui-make_default-ordered] Error 2
```

Is qt4.8 supported on CentOS8?

Comment: Have you tried 4.8.7?

Comment: Could you point out the steps you are following.